# android:layout_centerVerticle="true" not having an effect on my edit text

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a edittext and a button in a relative layout. Here is the xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/action_home_button"
        android:layout_width="35sp"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/home_button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/action_home_button"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:hint="Some hint..."
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#DDDDDD" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#EC9D21" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the button is centered in the `RelativeLayout` just fine, but my `EditText` is aligned to the top of the layout. Is there anything that I'm missing? Thank you in advance.

**Edit** Above I updated my xml. I set this as a custom view of my action bar. But that should not make a difference, since the button has no problem aligning to center vertical. Thanx

**Edit** EditText should be aligned center vertical

[image]

Comment: With these types of questions, its usually easier if you post the complete xml. Then we can copy/paste in our editor to see the results. Also, there's always the chance that another `View` is obscuring things.

Comment: What are those properties for below your `RelativeLayout`? Also, can you post an image of what you want it to look like? I think you have some unnecessary nesting...

Comment: Have you tried `android:layout_gravity`?

Comment: @t0mm13b `gravity` is not a property of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: I see that, thanks. But I can't test until I know what is going on below the end tag for the `RelativeLayout`. In the meantime, you might try removing `android:layout_marginBottom` from your child `RelativeLayout` and see what that does. You can use `marginTop` in your `ImageView`...that might get what you want

Comment: @codeMagic There, just a closing relativeLayout tag, ill try switching the margin now

Comment: @codeMagic I was referring to the EditText...and its not `gravity` - re-read my comment. :)

Comment: @t0mm13b ah, ok. But the text is centered. The `EditText` itself is not which is the problem.

Comment: `layout_gravity` still is not a property of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Have you tried changing the `background` of the EditText?  I'm pretty sure that the default EditText has some padding/margin underneath it by default.  I'm not sure if that is the 9-patch used as the background or if you can give it a negative bottom margin or something.  Keep in mind that the default EditText style is different between operating systems.

Comment: @Uxonith Hi, changing the background seemed to work, thanks for the tip. I will post the xml in a couple of moments

Comment: @codeMagic The suggestion Uxonith gave works fine for me. I am just thinking, what should be done if using the standard editText was your only option? Food for thought

Comment: @Lunchbox I'm not sure. Did you try my suggestion and it didn't work? That seems like it would work but without playing around with it, I'm not sure.

Comment: @codeMagic It still had the same effect, it doesnt make sense anyways, because the button aligned fine, but the edit text did not want to listen. When I changed the background though, it lined up the way it was supposed to

Comment: @Lunchbox ok, I'm not sure then off-hand without playing unless using `marginTop` on the `EditText` would work

Comment: @codeMagic `marginTop` would definitely work, but I'm not sure if it would display exactly in the center on every device. That's where the problem lies, lol. But thanx for the suggestion anyways

Comment: @codeMagic I'll try to figure it out without changing the background, because in some cases I might want to use the standard edit text and not change the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard EditTexts in some themes seem to have some built in `padding` or `margin` around and/or under it.  If you wish to eliminate this issue, then I would heavily suggest either using a [nine patch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html), background color, or some other form of custom background.

Trying to set a negative bottom margin or something crazy might fix the issue for one standard EditText, but you have to be careful between Android versions as their EditTexts can have different themes and give rather unexpected behavior.

As for why the theme designers chose to have this gap underneath is beyond me.  My best guess would be that is their way of "saving face" when the developer doesn't add a margin between vertically aligned EditTexts?

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Uxonith. Changing the background seemed to do the trick eg. `android:background="#000000"`. For me this works fine, because I had to change the background anyways, but if you need the standard edit text, this will not be a solution.

Comment: I guess I should have left an answer instead of a comment, so I just added one if you decide you want to accept it :)